# How to do insert in the middle of query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this function :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION func1()
  RETURNS void AS
$BODY$
declare
    row record;
    row2 record;
    v_id integer[];
begin
        for row in select * from A where .... order by ...
        loop
            for row2 in update B a set quantity=quantity2 from
            (select ... from... where....) q
            where .... returning a.id
            loop
                v_id=v_id||row2.id;                     
            end loop;
       end loop;

       more operations....
end;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
```

I need to add an `insert` operation BEFORE the `update  B` hapennds. beasicly before I do `quantity=quantity2`  I want to save the record with `quantity` in another table.

How do I "break" this query so that I can do both Insert and Update?

Comment: you can create a trigger  to perform(_insert into another_table_) while updating table  `B` . From where `quantity2` comes from in your function??

Comment: I can not, already considered it... this cause many problems (manly because I have no control of the order trigger execute). I need the other table to be ready before the "more operations...." code starts.

Comment: Are you looking for something like this -http://hastebin.com/wecocetepe.rb ?

Comment: yes that is the general idea... do the insert before the update

Comment: They comes from the query... I just need the correct structure.. I'll hadle the samll details of what to insert...

Comment: The row in `for row in select * from A` is never referenced. Please post real code, metasyntax is hard to debug. And please add the intended behaviour to your question (IMHO you don't even need a cursor loop)

Answer (score 0):

Traditionally it is done by a BEFORE or INSTEAD OF trigger.

If you don't want to use a trigger you can simply repeat your query.

Do `INSERT` of old values first:

```
INSERT INTO AnotherTable (quantity)
SELECT quantity
FROM B
WHERE <filter>
```

Then do the `UPDATE`:

```
update B
set quantity = q.quantity2 
from q
where <filter>
```

The inner `for row2` loop does something with IDs of all rows that were updated in `B`. It doesn't matter what it does. Use `INSERT ... SELECT` to save the values from table `B` into `AnotherTable` before they are updated. I don't really understand what's the problem here.

```
    for row in select * from A where .... order by ...
    loop

        INSERT INTO AnotherTable (quantity)
        SELECT quantity
        FROM B
        WHERE <some filter>
        ;

        for row2 in update B a set quantity=quantity2 from
        (select ... from... where....) q
        where <some filter> returning a.id
        loop
            v_id=v_id||row2.id;                     
        end loop;
   end loop;
```

Comment: This will give the insert the values of `quantity2` which are the new values... I need the old values... that were before the update.

Comment: The idea is that you `SELECT` from `B` the values that are in that table before the changes are made by `UPDATE` using the same filter in `WHERE`.

Comment: But where is the loop?  I don't see how I interate it to the function above.

Comment: I don't really understand the problem.